# Spark read csv with comma inside string

Tags: csv, pyspark, delimiter, databricks

536381,22411,JUMBO SHOPPER VINTAGE RED PAISLEY,10,12/1/2010 9:41,1.95,15311,United Kingdom

"536381,82567,""AIRLINE LOUNGE,METAL SIGN"",2,12/1/2010 9:41,2.1,15311,United Kingdom"

536381,21672,WHITE SPOT RED CERAMIC DRAWER KNOB,6,12/1/2010 9:41,1.25,15311,United Kingdom

These lines are example of rows in a csv file.
I'm trying to read it in Databricks, using:

```
df = spark.read.csv ('file.csv', sep=',', inferSchema = 'true', quote = '"')
```

but, the line in the middle and other similar are not getting into the right column because of the comma within the string. How can I workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the quote to:

```py
'""'
```

```py
df = spark.read.csv('file.csv', sep=',', inferSchema = 'true', quote = '""')
```

It looks like your data has double quotes - so when it's being read it sees the double quotes as being the start and end of the string.

Edit: I'm also assuming the problem comes in with this part:

```sh
""AIRLINE LOUNGE,METAL SIGN""
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks Ranvir for your help! Actually I had tried that, but it seemd quote only accepts one character, so it still doesn't work. It seems the issue was coming from the fact that I've opened the file with Excel to have a look at the data before uploading it to databricks and excel added this odd double quotes at the beginning and end of rows with commas between strings (and doubles the doubles quotes to identify the strings). Warned by a colleague, I've just solved it by downloading the file again from source and uploading to databricks before opening it!

Comment: Ah excel strikes again haha. Happy you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

this is not only related to Excel; I have the same issue when retrieving data from a source into Azure Synapse. the comma within one column causes the process to enclose entire column data with double quotes and including double quotes get doubled as shown above, second line (see [Retrieve CSV format over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801809/retrieve-csv-format-over-https))

Comment: Thanks for contributing by answering! Please add the actual solution in your answer as well: in this case all the useful info is behind that link (but links can go stale). You can use links as supporting/extra information but your answer should be readable and useful by just reading it. Thanks again :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33420502)