# Retrieve CSV format over https

Tags: csv, apache-spark, http, postman

I'm retrieving data in csv format from a web service using http request.
data can contain a web address with parms in json format ( [https://example.com?parm=abc&opt={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}](https://example.com?parm=abc&opt=%7B%22key1%22:%22value1%22,%22key2%22:%22value2%22%7D) )
the comma within the JSON string causes the subsequent data processing using spark to mess up the data.
the web service providing the data does not allow to change the csv delimiter.

resulting data in csv file is doubling double quotes inside like
'     "https....""key1"":""value1""...    '
Are there any options in the http protocol to 'correctly' transport/quote the data or is this rather a spark issue  ?

using Postman to analyse the 'look and feel' of the delivered data

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in spark
spark.read.load(file, format='csv', header = True, **quote = '"', escape = '"'**)